# Trying to set up .SSH keys to connect to Github via Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, cygwin, ssh-keys

I've just installed Cygwin on Windows 7 to develop RoR apps with, trouble is I am trying to connect Git with my Github account through Cygwin but for some reason when I run the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "myemail@etc.com"` it gives me back the message `"bash: ssh-keygen: command not found"`

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartle by the way but can't seem to find a solution.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chances are you probably forgot to install the openssh package when you installed Cygwin.

I've used this guide before, and everything was flawless(for ssh):

http://allthingsmarked.com/2006/08/17/how-to-set-up-a-windows-ssh-server-for-vnc-tunneling/

Comment: That's great thanks! Just forgot to install the openssh package.