# Setting up public/private keys for GITHUB via cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, cygwin

I am learning Ruby on Rails so I apologize if my lingo is not right. Let me explain what I am trying to do.

I am following the ruby and rails free tutorial. I am setting up public private keys for GITHUB via cygwin. I am using this tutorial: [Using Public/Private Keys with GIT](http://ccn.ucla.edu/wiki/index.php/Setting_Up_and_Using_Git#Using_Public.2FPrivate_Keys_with_GIT).

However I am guessing this is for using the GIT terminal. I am typing the following command in cygwin:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

It can't find that, so I added on git in front so that it would recognize it as a GIT command, so I did:

```
git ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

It now says `'ssh-keygen' is not a command`. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: why dont you accept the answer? If it also worked for you?

Answer (score 6):

`ssh-keygen` isn't a git command, only a shell command, as its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) illustrates.
If cygwin doesn't recognize that command, see "[Trying to set up .SSH keys to connect to Github via Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466583/trying-to-set-up-ssh-keys-to-connect-to-github-via-cygwin)":

> Chances are you probably forgot to **install the `openssh` package** when you installed Cygwin.

See the [Cygwin packages regex search for ssh-keygen](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=ssh-keygen).

See "[How to set up SSH (for the beginner)](http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html)" for a tutorial on SSH with Cygwin.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me. I went and installed openssh. Everything worked flawlessly.